# Tensorflow map_fn gives error: ValueError: No attr named '_XlaCompile'

Tags: tensorflow

I try to implement the 'batch hard' batches as described in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07737.pdf to use with a triplet loss. So input is of shape [batch_size, 32] and output should be a list representing triplets, so [[batch_size, 32], [batch_size, 32], [batch_size, 32]] when each individual example is of size (32,).

I implemented this with the following function, so basically using tf.map_fn:

```
def batch_hard(inputs):
    """ 
    Batch Hard triplets as described in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07737.pdf.
    For each sample in input the hardest positive and hardest negative
    in the given batch will be selected. A triplet is returned.
    """
    class_ids, f_anchor = inputs[0], inputs[1]

    def body(x):
        class_id, f = x[0], x[1]

        same_class = tf.equal(class_ids, class_id)

        positive = same_class
        negative = tf.logical_not(same_class)

        positive = tf.squeeze(positive)
        negative = tf.squeeze(negative)

        positive.set_shape([None])
        negative.set_shape([None])

        samples_pos = tf.boolean_mask(f_anchor, positive)
        samples_neg = tf.boolean_mask(f_anchor, negative)

        # Select hardest positive example
        distances = euclidean_distance(samples_pos, f)
        hardest_pos = samples_pos[tf.argmax(distances)]

        # Select hardest negative example
        distances = euclidean_distance(samples_neg, f)
        hardest_neg = samples_neg[tf.argmin(distances)]

        return [hardest_pos, hardest_neg]

    [f_pos, f_neg] = tf.map_fn(body, inputs, dtype=[tf.float32, tf.float32])
    return [f_anchor, f_pos, f_neg]
```

This works perfectly when I only perform a forward pass, with no train_op specified . However when I add this line `train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)` the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 348, in _MaybeCompile
    xla_compile = op.get_attr("_XlaCompile")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2003, in get_attr
    raise ValueError("No attr named '" + name + "' in " + str(self._node_def))
ValueError: No attr named '_XlaCompile' in name: "map/while/strided_slice"
op: "StridedSlice"
input: "map/while/boolean_mask/Gather"
input: "map/while/strided_slice/stack"
input: "map/while/strided_slice/stack_1"
input: "map/while/strided_slice/Cast"
attr {
  key: "Index"
  value {
    type: DT_INT64
  }
}
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "begin_mask"
  value {
    i: 0
  }
}
attr {
  key: "ellipsis_mask"
  value {
    i: 0
  }
}
attr {
  key: "end_mask"
  value {
    i: 0
  }
}
attr {
  key: "new_axis_mask"
  value {
    i: 0
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shrink_axis_mask"
  value {
    i: 1
  }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea what goes wrong?

A full example of this issue is here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0b5e9194ebf09be7ad2f0a740bf369b8

Edit: It seems the problems is in these lines

```
hardest_pos = samples_pos[tf.argmax(distances)]
```

replacing it with something like

```
hardest_pos = tf.zeros(32)
```

gives no errors, however how to solve this?

Comment: I think your problem may have something to do with the fact that argmax is non-differentiable. Hence why you are observing this error only when trying to optimize your network.